# Minimum Android version that support WhatsApp select-text function?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I had Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) with WhatsApp app installed.

On early days, I can select text in the WhatsApp app. But since updating WhatsApp to the later version, I cannot select text.

Another phone with Android 6 works just fine with newest version WhatsApp.

I suspect the new version of WhatsApp, when select text, has popup that not supported by Android 4.2.

So, what is minimum Android version that can support select text function in new version of WhatsApp?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. "*Another phone with Android 6 works just fine with newest version WhatsApp.*" have you checked its version from Android Settings - Apps - WhatsApp - App info? I can't recall when WhatsApp allowed the select-text function. Before the reaction popup, I believe it only allowed copying the whole message through the menu, was it before that? However, WhatsApp often deprecated older versions so they may not be able to work anymore even if the version is found.

Comment: At the very least, I found some old posts (since 2016) mentioning the same issue: [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-select-some-part-of-the-text-in-a-whatsapp-message.3295211/) (2016), [OnePlus Community](https://community.oneplus.com/thread/941750) (2018), [CCM](https://ccm.net/forum/affich-1144637-can-t-select-text) (2021), [AskMeFast](https://www.askmefast.com/How_do_i_select_a_part_of_the_Whatsapp_text_message_copy_and_paste-qna7913631.html#q8652317) (unknown)